# Objective C - Overriding a base class method - How to call subclass's method?

Tags: objective-c

I have a base class which is used extensively in my code, but when I subclass it the base class method gets called in the following example code:

```
SubClass *foo;
[array addObject:foo];

for ( BaseClass *bc in array ) {
  [bc foo];
}
```

Is there a way to get the subclass's foo method called without changing the for loop? Can I do something like

```
foo {
  if ( what_class_am_i_really != BaseClass ) [what_class_am_i_really foo];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C will automatically call the implementation of the subclass.

If it doesn't do this in your case, there's a bug somewhere in your code, and you need to show those methods.

Comment: I've added the adding of the subclass to the array. Logging the object's class shows the base class in the loop.

Comment: alloc wasn't of the subclass :)

Answer (score 2):

The subclass's method is called automatically. That's polymorphism. Casting it to the superclass does not invoke the superclass method.